# IIS not returns PDF only Excel in Web Api

Tags: c#, pdf, iis, itext

I build an app in .Net Core 2.1 with Vue, in debug mode everything is work fine, even, i print a ticket with Microsoft Printer PrintDocument. But when i release the web api and the Net Core 2.1 to publish in iis, the Web Api doesn't return the PDF, only gets an EXCEL docuemnt, the Excel works fine, but the PDF not.

I generate the PDF with ITextSharp.

I return the PDF like this:

```
          return new HttpResponseMessage
      {
        Content = new StreamContent(stream)
        {
          Headers =
        {
            ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf"),
            ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "myfile.pdf"
            }
        }
        },
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
      };
    }
```

How to return the pdf with IIS?

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to return pdf? Are you getting any error?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i not getting an error, only i get the response = OK, but with not pdf

Answer (score 0):

If it is return **OK** , then make check for the downloaded file if it is exist in the **download browser folder** or use another browser.